# Method returning DataTable with using

Tags: c#, datatable, idisposable

Consider the following example:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable()
{
    using(DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
        // fill DataTable logic
        return dt;
    }
}

public void main()
{
    DataTable dt = GetDataTable();

    // contine using dt
}
```

Should I expect `dt` to be usable in `main()`, or was the `DataTable` disposed of in `GetDataTable()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the `DataTable` will have been disposed when leaving the `using` block in `GetDataTable`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the `DataTable` will be disposed when the code exit the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) scope.

You should move the `using` to your `main()`

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable()

    // fill DataTable logic
    return dt;
}

public void main()
{
  using(DataTable dt = GetDataTable())
  {
  // contine using dt
  }//here the table is disposed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to replace

```
public  void main()
```

to

```
public static void Main()
```

---

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable()
{
  using(DataTable dt = new DataTable())
  {
    // fill DataTable logic
    return dt;
  }
}
```

once your code leave `GetDataTable`  `dt` will be disposed. Because `using` calls `IDisposible`

Answer (score 0):

```
    public DataTable GetValue(string name)
    {
        string connection = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-M5TQV9A;Initial Catalog=ALLTEST;Integrated Security=True";
        DataTable dt;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("up_searchUsers", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

search in the textbox then get your results! :) Happy C# Codding

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = GetValue(textBox1.Text);
```